# How to deselect selected text in an iPad application

Tags: ipad, uimenucontroller

I have a custom menu item (UIMenuItem) attached to a UIWebView.  When the user selects my custom menu item after selecting some text in the web view, I want to "deslect" the current text selection.  The problem is that the edit menu will pop up again when I show a modal form for some reason, I think because there is still a selected (highlighted) text range.  I want to programmatically "unselect" the selected text in my custom menu item handler, after I've captured the selected range.

Answer (score 6):

Use UIView's **userInteractionEnabled** property. Just disable user interaction and enable it back.

Like this:

```
myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
myWebView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner solution:

**Swift**

```
webView.endEditing(true)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[webView endEditing:YES]
```